# Listen to File Changes in Detail

Tags: linux, windows, macos, filesystems

I read about the capabilities to detect file and directory changes in modern days windows.

Is it correct that currently no possibility exist to monitor file changes down to the bytes or at least a single region ([from, to])?

I would like to see a history of file changes (that might compact over time) that reads like: file x - modified in region [start, end].

All I currently can do is: file x was modified by monitoring file events or if activated use the ntfs-event-log and obtain the same information but in the past.

Do I overlook things here?

Is it possible in Mac or Linux to obtain these region modified level of information? I have a very large file I want to monitor and sync.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows there exist filesystem filter drivers. On MacOS there's a choice of options, all of them are more limited and less flexible, than in Windows. On Linux there exists inotify, also more limited than Windows filter drivers.